# Access comment of fields on Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have migration like this

```
   public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('test', function($t){
         $t->increments('id')->comment('This is test'),
     });
    }
```

I want to access comment of `id` field on laravel blade

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
$tableColumnInfos = DB::select('SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM comments');
foreach ($tableColumnInfos as $tableColumnInfo) {
   echo $tableColumnInfo->Field . ' ' . $tableColumnInfo->Comment; 
}
```

Each `$tableColumnInfo` is

```
0 => {#581 ▼
    +"Field": "id"
    +"Type": "int(10) unsigned"
    +"Collation": null
    +"Null": "NO"
    +"Key": "PRI"
    +"Default": null
    +"Extra": "auto_increment"
    +"Privileges": "select,insert,update,references"
    +"Comment": "This is test"
  }
```

if you wont to only get id column info you can use

```
$idInfo = DB::select('SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM comments where FIELD="id"');
```

Also you can specify some columns

```
$idInfo = DB::select('SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM comments where FIELD IN ("id", "other_column")');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible.
Try to add this to constants in your model:

```
class Test extends model
{
   const COLUMN_COMMENTS = [
       'id' => 'This is test',
   ];
}
```

Migrate:

```
   public function up()
   {
      Schema::create('test', function($t){
         $t->increments('id')->comment(Test::COLUMN_COMMENTS['id']),
      });
   }
```

Blade:

```
{{ Test::COLUMN_COMMENTS['id'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$table_name = 'test';
$columns = \Schema::getColumnListing($table_name);
dd($columns);
```

Or just run regular db query to get it from information_schema:

```
select `column_name`, `column_type`, `column_default`, `column_comment`
from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` 
where `table_name` = 'table-name' 
and `table_schema` = 'db-name';
```

Comment will be in `column_comment` field.